# AWS RDS postgresql IOPS perfomance issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, memory-leaks, amazon-rds

We are using AWS db.m4.2xlarge RDS postgresql instance for Ruby on Rails Application. As per AWS  [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#USER_PIOPS.Realized)  IOPS Rate should be 8000 but our RDS instance not able to perform more then 3000 - 4000 IOPS writes.

We are running around 10 concurrent rake tasks to update the data into the database. We tried doubling the tasks but still IOPS rate remain same.

We analyzed Ruby code for any memory leaks and it looks fine, Also memory is not a problem in the rails App instance.

Any work around for this problem?

Comment: What storage type are you using? The rates in the documentation only apply to Provisioned IOPS storage - if you're using General Purpose storage, your throughput will be lower.

Comment: We are using General Purpose storage RDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the RDS storage documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#Concepts.Storage), "Provisioned IOPS storage is designed to meet the needs of I/O-intensive workloads, particularly database workloads, that are sensitive to storage performance and consistency in random access I/O throughput."

If you change from General Purpose storage to Provisioned IOPS, you should see a performance improvement.